# History timestemp shows wrong dates

Tags: 18.04, bash, time, history

when running the commands

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
history
```

the date output are wrong. For example the `sudo reboot` in line 1407 was done on 31/12/2019. I am not sure about the hours. 
How can I fix it?

Output example

```
1404  02/01/20 09:48:37 sudo apt-get update
 1405  02/01/20 09:48:37 sudo apt-get upgrade 
 1406  02/01/20 09:48:37 sudo apt autoremove
 1407  02/01/20 09:48:37 sudo reboot
 1408  02/01/20 09:48:43 cd aedata/ae/stats
 1409  02/01/20 09:48:48 cd aedata/ae/
 1410  02/01/20 09:48:57 cd /aedata/ae/
 1411  02/01/20 09:48:58 ls
 1412  02/01/20 09:49:08 clear
 1413  02/01/20 09:49:09 ll
 1414  02/01/20 09:49:57 ls
 1415  02/01/20 10:53:46 history
 1416  02/01/20 10:54:14 HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
 1417  02/01/20 10:54:18 clear
 1418  02/01/20 10:54:21 history
```

it seems that something is wrong with the system time. checking reboot and uptime it shows that the last reboot was 2 hours ago, but the uptime is 46 hours.

```
$ date
Thu Jan  2 11:57:58 MST 2020

$ last reboot
wtmp begins Thu Jan  2 09:48:37 2020

$ uptime
 11:58:27 up 1 day, 21:47,  1 user,  load average: 3.77, 5.09, 4.39
```

Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-72-generic x86_64)

Comment: The initial history entries all with the same time indicate that those were written to the history file **before** you set the HISTTIMEFORMAT variable. Since they don't have a timestamp associated with them, they are displayed with the timestamp of the HISTFILE itself.